# How to combine two python scripts

Tags: python

One of my python script is giving me several output (for eg. 1067879400 1067880600 1067881200 1067881800 1067882400 1067883000 1067883600). Now I want to supply these numbers or arguments to another python script. So how can I include both scripts in one script so that output from first script is given to another script as command line arguments.

Thanks

-Viral

Comment: Please show both the scripts ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) shows how you can call something from the command line from python.

Comment: Depending on your situation, it might be a good idea to keep the scripts separate and only pipe the results between the scripts with the shell. Something like `script1.py | script2.py`. In order for this to work you would have to make sure your scripts are writing (and reading) from STDIN/OUT.

Comment: You don't need to pipe or anything else like that, either keep it to a single script or import the functions.

Comment: Actually I cannot combine two scripts because other script contains several ipython modules which will not work with python. So basically I am looking for how to add command line arguments in call function?     from subprocess import call
call('test2.py' ) here I want to pass arguments

Comment: How could they not work if you have two python scripts, that makes no sense?

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** have to do it this way, you can consider something like:

```
os.system("script2.py arg1 arg2")
```

In the case of a list or dict, you can consider using `pickle` when preparing the data to be passed/received.

Comment: How will this pass args from one script to another?

Comment: Hi Reuben, how can I use `pickle` in this case? My script1.py gives my output like `num=['1067881800','1067881200','1067882400','1067880600','1067883000','1067883600','1067879400']` so how can I pass this argument to script2.py? Right now I am using `os.system(" python script2.py "+str(NUM))` in my `script1.py`. But it is not working.

Comment: `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()`. You can consider using @geckon's pipe solution with this also.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following options:

1) run the two scripts from your shell using a pipe like this:

```
first.py | second.py
```

2) re-write the scripts so you can import the first script in the second, for example like this:

the first script:

```
# first.py

# the method returning the numbers as a list (formerly putting them to stdout)
def get_numbers():
    # do something to collect the list of the numbers
    return numbers_list
```

the second script:

```
# second.py
from .first import get_numbers

# the method using the numbers (formerly getting them from stdin)
def process_numbers():
    numbers = get_numbers()
    # do something to process the numbers
```

If you really want to call the other script as is, you can do it this way:

```
#second.py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def process_numbers():
    p = Popen(["first.py", "argument"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    # the out variable now contains the standard output of the first script
    # do something to process the numbers
```